# ruby execute shell command error

Tags: ruby

Here is the code `do.rb`:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby

    def open
      fp = File.open("input")
      yield fp
      fp.close
    end

    open do |fp|
      while line = fp.gets
        puts `du #{line} -h`
        # puts `du -h #{line}` # this works fine
      end
    end
```

And the `input` file:

```
    1.rb
    2.rb
```

If I run `ruby do.rb`, it just returns a `command not found`.
And I have to change `-h` before `#{line}`.
I don't why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string returned by [`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) contains line separator.

You should remove the line separator using [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
puts `du #{line.chomp} -h`
```